# Подсписок первых N элементов

Tags: функции, list, условия, haskell

Подсписок первых n элементов, начиная с нулевого. Число n передает-
ся первым аргументом, исходныи̮ список — вторым. У пустого списка при любом числе возвращается пустой список. Предусмотреть ситуацию с числом элементов,
меньшим, чем значение n. Решить ее любым разумным способом. Список может
быть потенциально бесконечным.
**сама функция у меня получилась, но я никак не могу вклинить туда условие, что будет если n больше числа элементов в списке. Штука еще и в том, что функции свертки использовать нельзя. Как исправить это условие?**

```
length' :: [a] -> Int
length' [] = 0
length' (x:xs) = length' xs + 1 
take' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take' n _ | n <= 0 = []
          | (n > (length' xs)) = error "error!!!"
take' _ [] =  []
take' n (x:xs) =  x : take' (n-1) xs
```

Comment: Я не настоящий сварщик, но мне кажется что условие на длину списка тут лишнее: при n > длины отдать всё что есть. Это как раз обрабатывается последними двумя строками.

Comment: `n > length' xs` приведет к расходимости (зависанию) на бесконечном списке. Если действительно хотите завершать выполнение с ошибкой, при `n` > длины списка, делайте это в следующем уравнении, когда список пустой, а `n` не равно `0`.

Comment: вы не совсем поняли. При вводе пустого списка с любым n должен быть выведен пустой список, в любом случае. Но если список не пустой, а n больше кол-ва элементов в списке, то нужно вывести сообщение об ошибке. Поэтому, думаю, должна быть задействована функция длины. Только как ее грамотно вставить в условие ..?

Comment: @A_Hatake почему вы считаете, что "Решить ее любым разумным способом" это вывести ошибку? Встроенная функция `take` в этом случае возвращает столько элементов, сколько есть. Это разумный способ.

Comment: @extrn, так в данном случае мы сами пишем take, через рекурсию. Правильно ли я понимаю, что ваше рассуждение распространяется и на этот случай?

Comment: @A_Hatake ну встроенная в GHC тоже выполнена в виде рекурсии (правда при включенной оптимизации будет использована версия со сверткой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам действительно так нужно завершить выполнение с ошибкой при неполном списке, но не при изначально пустом, перенесите рекурсию во вспомогательную функцию

```
take' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take' n _ | n <= 0 = []
take' _ [] =  []
take' n xs = go n xs
  where
    go 0 _ = []
    go n (x:xs) = x : go (n-1) xs
    go _ _ = error "error"
```